# Log file creation with date/time in filename

Tags: node.js, fs

How can make every time the program is launched, that the logs are overwritten into a new file? And so that the end of the file name was the date and time of the file creation.

```
var fs  = require('fs');

var ws = fs.createWriteStream('test.log', { 
    'flags'   : 'w',
    'encoding': 'utf8',
    'mode'    : 0666,
});

process.stdout.wr = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.er = process.stderr.write;

process.stdout.write = function(mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.wr(mes, c)   
};

process.stderr.write = function(mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.er(mes, c)   
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a code like this:

```
const date = new Date();
const timestamp = date.getTime();

var ws = fs.createWriteStream(`test-${timestamp}.log`, { 
    'flags'   : 'w',
    'encoding': 'utf8',
    'mode'    : 0666,
});
```

Log filenames will be something like `test-1553591263787.log`, `test-1553591318028.log`...

If you want a custom date/time format, check [this SO question about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date).

Comment: I know this is old, but I just wanted to point out that in the first line, `const data` should be `const date`.

Comment: thank you @Josh, I fixed the typo in the code